# How do I handle OAuth2 in back-end microservices and front-end?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, frontend, backend, microservices

I’m developing back-end services and securing it using my custom OAuth server. At front-end I’m planning to support facebook, google and username and password OAuth. How can I implement this using spring boot ?

Comment: Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

### [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)

This tutorial demonstrates how to create a Spring Boot app that leverages OAuth2 authorization via Facebook and GitHub.

### [Spring Boot + Spring Security + OAuth2 + Microservices](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v)

This tutorial demonstrates how to create a microservices architecture with a Spring Boot stack that separates your concerns into the following apps: UI, Auth, Resource.